# SCITE4Autohotkey debugger not working

Tags: autohotkey

I installed SCITE4Autohotkey under autohotkey last version
everything work ok,
but I cannot activate the debugger.
when I set the bullet stop near line no (and press debug mode). the code is not stopped
on [F5] or RUN

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

End the process InternalAHK.exe*32

Answer (score 0):

Save your file first.
Set your stop bullets (red dots) by clicking just next to the line numbers.
Go to first line of code, press debug (little insect) first (Icon changes and new single line icons appear), then press Run (blue triangle) or single line (blue arrows).
"Run" will now run the code until the first red dot, you can then continue with single line execution (Blue arrows) or continue with run (blue triangle) until the next red stop bullet.
Works flawlessly with my system (Win-7, AHK_L).

Answer (score 0):

Fix this issue by simply selecting a platform, just click this 
[image: Set current platform button (image here)] and select **Default** from the dropdown menu.

(I was not able to run and debug scripts inside SciTE4AutoHotkey)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I need to close the file and reopen it and then I'm able to create breakpoints.